# Unable to switch user since 21.10 upgrade

Tags: users, 21.10, switch-user

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10 I'm not able to switch users. I can log in as either user fine to begin with, but if I select switch user once logged in I get the user login screen as normal, then when I enter the username and password for the second user I get a black screen with a blinking cursor in the top left corner.

I've tried creating a new user and the same thing happens with that user. I can reboot and log in as any of the users fine if they are first.

Anyone have any ideas how I can troubleshoot this? Thanks.